# Is it possible to dynamically set the type of a function argument in a generic function based upon the presence of a specific generic type argument?

Tags: typescript

I am a newbie Typescript user trying to learn generics.

I am trying to return an object with a property type set according to the presence / absence of a type argument in the generic function. Is this possible in typescript? I have included a short example in the code listing below and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYBVwQDwoDRQHIB8UAvPlBAB7ATIDOUCEAbhAE5QD8UKUAXPgG4AUKEhQACgEMQAGziSkWXHmKMWrIqQDeQqHqisItMIloR+OXfsMBHAK5Hg-WsFYBLBAHNsVvUknAkvzwyGiQSvgEPgC+QkIA9ABUibqJ3KwgHp5QwHBQSCAIkgC2bgDGkjIyIFBmwDkAFtCi0HAAZlABrm4ARnbU+QGSOXk8bh14UG70amy4cMBNrADu0xCpjc3oUO2DgbUNcHYySFA90DzLTQhk0wwLDMxsAHQbAJIdi3d3CA8mtLRejJmtcpvRFq0ENUoMtpCNOmUGm4no07otWEdPA0oHYEG5EDl0PQIM9PM8oBsIYSxLt-PswBjIKxQFMblJZPJTrRDsdTuc9kFuFAAD74Z7i1LxIRtXFlYD4m7FEAAMVlEUmlGodEe6gIAApDMZTOZuLhbA4XM5ul4AJT8dlyBRKQjS2XyglK1UIMrq-WGkwIMwWM0QeyOK3uLy4X6sYqVNZIDj8PB2iTSR2KHCRKA6fRTDp6mNxmQJm053x5qBlUz1MDpzn2+tOrOEEjlysdgxGANBrtGwMQHydyvm8NdsMuIfD-R0wVF+NmJAVvPRYTDwzAOysG51jkKASdiuxPMQGRmdud6uB2tNpCNveZzQX6d9nsm-3Gqcv0eW8cW4BftOs78B+A6ASua6dhuW47rekF6LEsRCFeLh9scwB4HAsYLhApykJ6aouJG3gMHYxTnBoeoAOSgWYADK1qeFRuA0aG-4McRzFQAAjAATAAzAALDawgoXAwLPHInh6gABigTT3NhJaLmhMj1HcAAkWgAFJ0QA8ngzxEVk4wgAaRjoZhSkJtGxwyLgvE2tEMkichNaqcAACqCDzspuFtgR3oYMZXj6qx-b0YxXGsROwAcVkVGuWJElSbJ8nQLivkJh5YJQFpukGUZjGmeZtDod5WWLrZVQOU5LnCEAA)

```
type CondType<T, N> = N extends never ? T : N;
type Payload<T, N=never> = {
    response: T,
    request: string,
    data: CondType<T, N>,
}

/**
 * Trying to dynamically set the type of attribute data to T if N is never, otherwise
 * the type of data should be T when N is not never.
 * If this is not possible then is the only way to achieve this through union types e.g. 
 * the type of data property in Payload should be data: T | N...
 */
function myFunc<T, N extends never>(response: T, request: string): Payload<T,N>
function myFunc<T, N>(response: T, request: string, normalised?: N): Payload<T, N> {
    if (normalised) {
        const payload: Payload<T, N> = {
            response: response,
            request: request,
            data: normalised
        };
        return payload;       
    }
    else {
        const payload: Payload<T> = {
            response: response,
            request: request,
            data: response,
        };
        return payload;
    }
}

const resultNormalised = myFunc<string, number>('responseString', 'requestString', 1234);
console.log(`The normalised result is ${JSON.stringify(resultNormalised, null, 2)}`);
const resultUnnormalised = myFunc<string>('responseString', 'requestString');
console.log(`The unnormalised result is ${JSON.stringify(resultUnnormalised, null, 2)}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the conditional type is buying you much here.  Your `CondType<T, N>` definition seems to unintentionally be a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), and will not always evaluate to what you want, especially when checking against `never`:

```
type CondType<T, N> = N extends never ? T : N;
type Okay = CondType<string, number>; // number
type Oops = CondType<string, never>;  // never !!!
```

If you are already willing to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for `myFunc()`, then the following is probably the simplest solution with no conditional types:

```
type Payload<T, D> = {
    response: T,
    request: string,
    data: D
}

// call signatures
function myFunc<T>(response: T, request: string): Payload<T, T>;
function myFunc<T, N>(response: T, request: string, normalised: N): Payload<T, N>;
// impl
function myFunc<T, N>(response: T, request: string, normalised?: N): Payload<T, T | N> {
    return {
        response,
        request,
        data: normalised || response
    }
}
```

Note that overloads have call signatures with no implementation, seen by the callers of the function, followed by an implementation with a signature that is not seen by the callers of the function.  In your example code it looks like you thought the implementation signature was callable.  Anyway, the above has two call signatures, corresponding to the two ways you'd like to call the function.  The implementation has a looser signature, which is not strictly type-safe, so it's up to you to make sure that the implementation conforms to each call signature.

Anyway, let's make sure it works:

```
const resultNormalised = myFunc('responseString', 'requestString', 1234);
// const resultNormalised: Payload<string, number>

const resultUnnormalised = myFunc('responseString', 'requestString');
// const resultUnnormalised: Payload<string, string>
```

Looks good.  Also note that you often don't have to manually specify the generic type parameters when you call the function since they are inferred by the compiler based on the values you pass.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYBVwQDwoDRQHIB8UAvPlBAB7ATIDOUCEAbhAE5QD8UKUAXPgG4AUKEhQA8gGsAhiBKxEqdBlrBWASwQBzXAgCuAWwBGbAgKgB6Cw0MnWI9BLhh6peMjSQVazTobNTc0trRhZ2AEJIoWiHMQAFWQAbOGkkLFwAESJSAG8hKAKoVghaMERaCH4cfMLigEc9EuB+VQ1tbBqCpGlgaX4MoQBfaIAzPQQAY2B1RCgDEAAxcYmsAgAKYtLyyu5cesbVFp9tAEp+BJBk1PTuMyExyenZ+aXJm8INkrKECqq9iAaTSObT8CDgrAM0kS6gqSH4eDOUAuVzSOHwdweUxmCDmi2W73Wm2+v12RQBB2aUFavl04Mh0NhHHhiORKVRuB4AB90VA8oUycA9KwcXz+bUvtsOmLxYDVFLpVBur1+GCIVCYRAkFBOdyidtOlBhsNohNysAybQ9IlgHg6erYfIXss1gByPU-CAAZWOWhduDd5Ka3pBfqgAEYAEwAZgALCdhFYoKafubNlabXaGZrzkk2d4QbpbKYhMnaHBEhAAHTJLRrAAGKAAFtBVfSNVq09aoDCoAASHIAKU94jwlep2nUIxAn0t1ttaqzSELiUSuAjJ0GdfjJbNFvTAFUEK37ZrHXjJq73RVg75QwHZcAb9oXdvE6XUyUD0fM+2c5c8+OfiAQQO4-OWVY1vWTbQOMx6LnuXY9v2Q4jmOPqTtOnbAIecHtsuq5QOum7bkAA)